# Display username after login in cakephp3

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I want to display username after login in cakephp3. I write follow code but part of show username doesn't work. user after login redirect to main page.

```
Hi <?php print $this->request->session()->read('User',$user); ?>
```

login in UserController:

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->session()->read('login_ok') == '1') {
        $this->redirect(['controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'main']);
    }
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        //$hasher = new DefaultPasswordHasher();
        $count = $this->Users->find()
                ->where(['username' => $this->request->data['username'],
                    //    'password' => $this->request->data['password']])
                    'password' => md5($this->request->data['password'])])
                ->count();
        if ($count > 0) {
            $result = true;
            $this->request->session()->write('User', $user); //store username
            $this->request->session()->write('login_ok', '1');
            $this->redirect(['controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'main']);

        } else {
            $result = false;
        }
        $this->set('result', $result);
    }
}   

public function main() {
    if ($this->request->session()->read('login_ok') != '1') {
        $this->redirect(['controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login']);
    }

    $query = $this->request->session()->write('User',$user);
    $this->set('user', $query);
}
```

and this main.ctp codes:

```
Hi <?php print $this->request->session()->read('User', $user); ?>
```

Can you help in making this Code OR Suggest a new code ?

Comment: CakePHP ships with an authentication layer - you should make use of it. **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html**

Comment: better use **AuthComponent** http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html read this tutorial http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html#authentication-login-and-logout

Comment: Thanks but I read this tutorial before. I want to use from this method.

Comment: Why are you using a framework if you're not planning on using the methods it provides you to do things like authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really be using the cakephp **AuthComponent** and the functions that's made for this for example identifiying the user trying to login with **identify()**.

There is really no point using a framework if you're not going to use the functions provided by the framework as *N Nem* pointed out in the comments.

In the snippet you posted, you seem to never set the $user variable when you write to the session. You need to set it to be able to read it.

The following code is how you're supposed to do it in Cakephp 3 i really suggest you use that approach.

> AppController.php

```
public function initialize()
{
        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
                'loginAction' => [
                        'controller' => 'Users',
                        'action' => 'login'
                ],
                'loginRedirect' => [
                        'controller' => 'Start',
                        'action' => 'index'
                ],
                'logoutRedirect' => [
                        'controller' => 'Users',
                        'action' => 'login'
                ],
                'authenticate' => [
                        'Form'
                ],
        ]);
}
```

> UsersController.php

```
public function login()
{
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $user = $this->Auth->identify();
            if ($user) {
                $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('Username or password is incorrect'), [
                    'key' => 'auth'
                ]);
            }
        }
}
```

> Model/Entity/User.php

```
protected function _setPassword($password)
{
       return (new DefaultPasswordHasher)->hash($password);
}
```

Comment: OK. what is your suggest for display username after login? In fact,this is my question.

Comment: In my ssuggested approach that would be to use the AuthComponent as i said. $this->Auth->user('username'); In your current code, you better set the $user variable first and then access $this->request->session as you are.

Comment: you where right. I done login by Authcomponent and I used from      <?php print $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.username'); ?>     just. thankyou